# Connectedness of A={$(x,y):x \in \mathbb{I}\,$ or$ \, y \in \mathbb{I}$}

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

i have the following problem about connectedness, prove that in the Euclidean plane

A={$(x,y):x \in \mathbb{I}\,$ or$ \, y \in \mathbb{I}$} is connected

(This is my interpretation of the exercise, since the statement says: “show that the set of points on the plane with at least one irrational coordinate is a connected set in the usual metric.”)

I have tried in several ways, but it causes me a problem, that some of the coordinates have to be irrational

Comment: It really depends on what $\mathbb{I}$ is.

Comment: @copper.hat - the OP makes it clear that it stands for the irrational numbers

Comment: The set of numbers irrationals

Comment: You could also use $\mathbb{Q}^c$.

Comment: The complement of a countably infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is always path connected. Therefore, $A$ is path connected.